# R functions to get key based on value of vector

Tags: r

Is there any R function to find key of max value of an vector?

We have similar function as `list_name.index(max(list_name))` in python.

Comment: Thinking which or match maybe? Perhaps have a look over at  https://www.delftstack.com/howto/r/find-index-in-r/.

Answer (score 1):

Are you looking for `which.max()`?

```
vec = c(1,4,6,100,2)
which.max(vec)
#> 4
```